# Can I merge attributes to be a sub-attribute of another?

Tags: attributes

Can I merge attributes to be a sub-attribute of another?

I have two attributes, capacity and measure.  Each have units of measure and essentially do the same thing.

Is there an easy way to do it?  Is exporting to a CSV, making the changes, and then importing them back a viable option?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no, product attributes don't have hierarchy.  There isn't really a long answer.